# Azerbaijan Transit Visa for Iranian Citizens

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, iranian-citizens, azerbaijan

Do Iranian citizens need a transit visa for travelling by airplane from Tehran, Iran to Istanbul, Turkey via Baku, Azerbaijan?

Comment: By what means of transportation are you travelling? This doesn't make sense, because direct flights IKA-IST are available, and Azerbaijan is not between Iran and Turkey by road either.

Comment: By airplane. Of course there are direct flights, but sometimes flights with changing are much cheaper.

Comment: Interesting. The cheapest flight I could find with routing through Baku (flying one week from today) is IRR 4219000 and the cheapest direct flight is IRR 4625000. So you are right.

Comment: Where did you find this flights? I searched for them on a German website with different prices?

Comment: That's pretty common. You'll find different prices based on the country where the tickets are sold.

Comment: [ITA Matrix](https://matrix.itasoftware.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No** you [don't need a transit visa](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=AZ&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), provided you have proof of onward travel and remain in Azerbaijan for less than 72h.

However, make sure you don't need to transfer terminals at Baku airport, because then you'll need a visa.

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>   - Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 72 hours.
>   - Stateless persons and refugees holding onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>   - TWOV is not possible between Terminal 1 and Terminal 2 at BAKU (GYD).

Comment: From what I understand, the possibility of changing terminals was an issue when T1 was under renovation and international flights might have arrived or departed from either terminal, but the renovations were completed in 2014 and now international flights should all be in T1, and T2 should be all domestic. Before the T1 renovations, T2 was the international terminal.